# Solving vector dependence with variable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The problem:

Given:

Vector $U$: \begin{bmatrix} a \\ a \\ 1\end{bmatrix}

Vector $V$: \begin{bmatrix} a \\ 1 \\ a\end{bmatrix}

Vector $W$: \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}

Find the variable $a$ where  the set of vectors $U$ $V$ and $W$, are dependent.

Now just looking at the vectors I can see that 1 is an answer, but is there a better way of solving it so that you can get all the solutions that can make $a$ dependent?  Do I have to do Gauss Elimination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one method. Let

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & a & a \\
1 & a & 1 \\
1 & 1 & a \\
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Now the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent if and only if $\det(A) = 0$. We have $\det(A) = -a^2 + 2a - 1 = -(a - 1)^2$, so $a = 1$ is the only solution.